# QR code -> immediate app download

Tags: java, qr-code

We have placed an app on itunes and googlestore, and my boss is doing a promotional campaign with QR codes.

But the client demands that as soon as the QR code is scanned, the device immediately and automatically starts downloading and installing the app.

So far, all i was able to do, was to make QR codes which contain links to the app on playstore/itunes, but that's not what the client wants.

Can such a thing be made and how ?

I am considering to use http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ in backend to click the download button, and then returning the received file to the client, but is there perhaps a better way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it's feasible, but I'd say it's probably not recommended as a general practice in the first place. You might annoy or scare off prospective users.

Comment: possibly you could prompt the user to download forcefully, instead installing it simultaneously.

Comment: Backend? What backend? All I see in the question is the app in the play store, a QR code in a magazine or whatever, and the end user with his clean phone.

Comment: The app in question is a client-server app. The server side is written in JAVA.

Comment: That doesn't help if the app is not on the phone already. Classic Chicken-egg problem. It would work for updates though.

Comment: The QR Code contains an url to where the app is on itunes/playstore. Once scanned, they need to be opened up in the browser, and then the appropriate app(itunes/playstore) and then the user clicks the install button. The client wants QR Codes which will, immediately upon being scanned, download and install the app automatically. Can such a thing be done ?

Comment: If I encountered that behavior I'd consider it _hostile_ and would cease contact with the app's creator.  This is a Really Bad Idea.